# Criteria Query Many To Many

Tags: hibernate

I have created the HQL of below mentioned SQL but I am unable to execute it by Criteria and Sub query. Please help me to execute the following queries (SQL & HQL) through Criteria. Thanks in **Advance**...

**SQL:**

```
SELECT * FROM app_interface ain WHERE ain.id IN (SELECT ai.id FROM app_interface ai INNER JOIN app_module_interface ami ON ami.interface_id = ai.id INNER JOIN app_module am ON am.id = ami.module_id WHERE am.id = :id
```

**HQL:**

```
FROM AppModule oam WHERE oam.id IN(SELECT am.id FROM AppModule am INNER JOIN am.appRoles ar WHERE ar.id = :id)
```

Through Criteria Needed…..?????

Scenario:

```
public class AppModule implements java.io.Serializable {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
private Integer id;

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "appModules")  
private Set<AppRole> appRoles = new HashSet<AppRole>(0);
```

}

public class AppRole implements java.io.Serializable {

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
private Integer id;

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@OrderBy("name")
@JoinTable(name = "app_role_module", joinColumns = {
@JoinColumn(name = "role_id", nullable = false, updatable = false)}, inverseJoinColumns = {
    @JoinColumn(name = "module_id", nullable = false, updatable = false)})
private Set<AppModule> appModules = new HashSet<AppModule>(0);
```

}

Answer (score 3):

Well, first of all, your query is too complex. It could be rewritten as

```
select distinct am from AppModule am 
inner join am.appRoles ar 
WHERE ar.id = :id
```

I don't know why you want to use criteria instead of this simple and readable HQL query, but if you really want to, then use

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(AppModule.class, "am");
c.createAlias("am.appRoles", "ar");
c.add(Restrictions.eq("ar.id", theRoleId));
c.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
```

EDIT:

If you want to implement the query

```
from AppModule oam WHERE oam.id not in (
    select am.id from AppModule am inner am.appRoles ar where ar.id = :id)
```

, then you can use the following code:

```
DetachedCriteria dc = DetachedCriteria.forClass(AppModule.class, "am");
dc.createAlias("am.appRoles", "ar");
dc.add(Restrictions.eq("ar.id", theRoleId));
dc.setProjection(Projections.id());

Criteria c = session.createCriteria(AppModule.class, "oam");
c.add(SubQueries.propertyNotIn("oam.id", dc));
```

Comment: I am new to Hibernate but not too new :). But any how... Thanks

Comment: This answer is about IN operator. But i also required 'FROM AppModule oam WHERE oam.id NOT IN(SELECT am.id FROM AppModule am INNER JOIN am.appRoles ar WHERE ar.id = :id)'

Comment: Here the result ' /* criteria query */ select
        this_.id as id3_0_,
        this_.inserted_by as inserted4_3_0_,
        this_.insertion_date as insertion2_3_0_,
        this_.name as name3_0_ 
    from
        app_module this_ 
    where
        this_.id not in (
            select
                this0__.id as y0_ 
            from
                app_module this0__ 
            where
                ar1_.id=?
        )
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query'